# Cards for free hero power

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone, each Hero Power costs 2 mana. The card [Maiden of the Lake](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Maiden_of_the_Lake) for instance sets the mana cost to 1 while it is active on the board.

I know that having 2 of them does not make the Hero Power free, as both cards will set the mana cost to 1 meaning one of them has no effect at all.

So are there cards that make the hero power free or are there cards that reduce the (current) mana cost by 1?

Just a beginner by the way, so I might just have missed some cards.

Comment: That would be incredibly broken in combination with [Coldarra Drake](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/22261-coldarra-drake).

Comment: I suppose that also answers my question to some degree. No wonder it's not possible.

Comment: If you are interested in a free hero power, the boss fight against Rafaam in the final wing of the League of Explorers singleplayer campaign gives you a special hero power that costs 0 mana. Especially fun with a Coldarra drake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are currently three cards that have an effect on the cost of a hero power, all from the *The Grand Tournament* set.

These cards are:

Maiden of the Lake: The card mentioned in your original post. It reads "Your hero power costs (1)." This effect lasts for as long as Maiden of the Lake is on the board.

Fencing Coach: This is the card most similar to what you're asking. It reads "Battlecry: The next time you use your hero power, it costs (2) less." This Battlecry effects the Hero Power itself, so is lost if you change hero powers.

Saboteur: Least relevant, but included for completeness. This card reads "Battlecry: Your opponent's hero power costs (5) more next turn."

In conclusion, there is no way to permanently reduce hero power cost below 1.

As of the Mean Streets of Gadgetzan expansion, a new Priest card called [Raza the Chained](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Raza_the_Chained) will reduce your hero power cost to 0 for the rest of the match when the battlecry is activated.

While this card is in priest, it has some interesting possible synergies when comboed with Sir Finley Mrrgglton and [Kabal Courior](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kabal_Courier), as you could discover a Coldarra Drake for infinite hero powers with the power you receive from Finley.

Comment: Accepted this one as it has a bit more information.

Answer (score 4):

There are no cards that make the hero power cost 0 permanently. But the card "Fencing Coach" from the "The Grand Tournament" expansion makes the next usage of your hero power cost 2 less. You can even carry this discount over to future turns.